# What does the >> operator do in python?

Tags: python

I found this code on a project, and I do not know what the `>>` does. Does anyone have an explanation?

```
def save(self, fpath=None):
        """
        Save the JSON data to fpath. This is done automatically if the
        game is over.
        """
        if fpath is None:
            fpath = _jsonf % self.eid
        try:
            print >> gzip.open(fpath, 'w+'), self.rawData,
        except IOError:
            print >> sys.stderr, "Could not cache JSON data. Please " \
                                 "make '%s' writable." \
                                 % os.path.dirname(fpath)
```

I know that this code is taking information from other files and object within the module, and I know how the code works overall. Only the `print >>` is confusing me. When this module is installed in a directory without write access, the message `Could not cache...` comes up. The entire file is located [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame/blob/master/nflgame/game.py#L339), but I doubt that it will help at all.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the referenced question _"Python How to simply redirect output of print to a TXT file with a new line created for each redirect"_. In the referenced question, the ">>" operator is used as part of a solution but its use is not explained in much detail. In fact I found the referenced question first and since it did not answer my question of what exactly the ">>" operator does, I searched further and found this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>>` prints to a file like object

> `print` also has an extended form, defined by the second portion of the syntax described above. This form is sometimes referred to as “`print` chevron.” In this form, the first expression after the `>>` must evaluate to a *“file-like”* object, specifically an object that has a `write()` method as described above. With this extended form, the subsequent expressions are printed to this file object. If the first expression evaluates to `None`, then `sys.stdout` is used as the file for output.

[`print statement`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print)

In this case it prints an error message to `stderr`

Comment: Can you please leave a link to where you found that passage of information?

Comment: Thanks for the help!